# Unix timestamp is not correct in JavaScript, but is correct according to other sources

Tags: javascript, date, unix-timestamp

This timestamp `1604978063` is not correct according to `new Date(1604978063)`

It returns the following:

```
Date Mon Jan 19 1970 05:49:38 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

When I look it up on DuckDuckGo, it looks correct.
[image: DDG results]

What's happening here?

Comment: javsacript holds time as milliseconds, unix as seconds ...

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's timestamps are not standard unix timestamps. They use milliseconds and therefore require a multiplication by 1000:

```
new Date(1604978063 * 1000)
```